# Функция обстоятельства места

Tags: обстоятельство

В каком предложении смысловая функция обстоятельства места не такая, как в остальных и почему?

1. Опытны фотограф углядел маленькое пятнышко в самом углу снимка.
2. Прибор зафиксировал неопознанный объект в небе над городом.
3. Я заметил конверт в правом ящике стола.
4. Мы услышали крики в соседней комнате.

(Или, возможно, везде одна и та же функция?)

Comment: Это не д/з, а олимпиада. Самому кажется, что везде одна и та же, но хотелось бы узнать другие мнения.

Answer (score 1):

1. Опытный фотограф углядел маленькое пятнышко в самом **углу** снимка.

Везде обстоятельство места в предложном падеже, а здесь в местном(втором предложном) - указывает на положение в пространстве.

Форма местного падежа совпадает в единственном числе с формой дательного падежа -у, но имеет ударение на последнем слоге, например: в лесу - к ле́су

Comment: Судя по ответам к олимпиаде, везде один и тот же смысл. Да и второй предложный (местный) ведь указывает на место, равно как и предложный (в одной из своих функций).

Comment: А есть ответы? А для какого класса? Если для младшего - ладно, а если для старшего - надо оспорить. Это опять "Медвежонок"?

Comment: Ответы есть, но пояснений ― нет. 10-11.  Нет, если бы ― "Ломоносов".

Comment: Ну, это несерьёзно, ведь определительный смысл есть. Это как "люминь - самый лёгкий железо"

Answer (score 1):

Мы услышали крики **в соседней комнате**.

В соседней комнате ― обстоятельственное определение: крики (какие? откуда?) в соседней комнате, это не обстоятельство места для сказуемого "услышали", так как "мы" находились в это время не в соседней комнате.

Comment: Я об этом тоже подумала, но тогда вопрос бы звучал по-другому, это не называли бы обстоятельством места. В этом смысле это несогласованное определение Хотя кто их знает, что они имели в виду.

Comment: Можно считать, что это обстоятельство места (откуда?) или обстоятельственное определение (какие?, но в любом случае оно относится  не к сказуемому, как в других примерах, а к дополнению

Comment: Может, и так - смысл обстоятельства с оттенком определения